# Ignore lines that start with two possible patterns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to analyse a source code and output each different function or subroutine to a file. My problem is that the source code can be something like this:

```
SUBROUTINE ABC
---
END SUBROUTINE
---
#SUBROUTINE to compute...
SUBROUTINE Dummy
---
      WRITE SUBROUTINE XX has finished...
END SUBROUTINE
```

So, I am able to avoid the commented lines with the following command.

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1};/^[^#]*subroutine/{flag=1;s="tmp_s_"++i}/end subroutine/{flag=0} flag {print $0 > s}' $sourcecodefile
```

But I want to avoid also the lines that have WRITE before the word Subroutine. I try this command but it doesn't work properly:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1};/[^#|WRITE]*subroutine/{flag=1;s="tmp_s_"++i}/end subroutine/{flag=0} flag {print $0 > s}' $sourcecodefile
```

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do, rather than just showing us how you tried to do it and leaving it to us to figure out your objective from your command that doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use two conditions instead of one:

```
... /^[^#]*subroutine/ && $0 !~ /write subroutine/ ...
```